# Number of departures in queues as an integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

In a queue with unit mean Poisson service times the number of departures are given by
$$D(t)=\int_0^t \mathcal N(ds)$$

where $\mathcal N$ is the unit mean Poisson process. How should I think of this integral? Should I think of it as an integral with respect to a point measure where there is a point of unit mass whenever there is a service completion?

Comment: That is how I would interpret the given integral, but there is a catch: The expression $\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ is not well-defined if $\mu$ has point masses at $0$ or at $t$. And this is precisely the case for the (random) point measure $\mathcal{N}$. So, I would rather write $$D(t)=\int_{[0,t]}\mathcal{N}(\mathrm{d}s).$$ for clarity.

Comment: Then it is well-known that $\mathcal{N}$ can be realized as a random set of points $\{0\leq X_1\leq X_2\leq \ldots\}$ (where $X_1, X_2-X_1, X_3-X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. and exponential), and so, $D(t)$ can be recast as $$D(t)=\int_{[0,t]}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\delta_{X_k}(\mathrm{d}s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\delta_{X_k}([0, t])=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{I}_{\{X_k\leq t\}},$$ which counts the number of Poisson points lying in the interval $[0,t]$.